# Assembly: initializer magnitude too large for specified size

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to learn how to write my output in Assembly
I made this code separately from the orginal code only for that purpose
i'm planning to implement this after i successfully record sth...
please help! thank you all in advance

There are bunch of errors in this code
but first i want to know the reason for the error A2071 : initializer magnitude too large for specified size (line 10)

```
TITLE PHW05    (s151619hw05.asm)
;

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

startmessage db "Start$"
msg db "display this message$"
FileName db "abcd.txt"
handle dw ?

.code
main PROC

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov dx,offset startmessage
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov dx,offset Filename
xor cx,cx
mov ah, 3ch
int 21h

mov dx, offset filename
mov al,2
mov ah,3dh
int 21h

mov handle, ax

mov dx,offset msg
mov bx,handle
mov cx,21
mov ah,40h
int 21h

mov bx,handle
mov ah,3eh
int 21h


;lea dx, offset msg
;mov ah, 40h
;mov cx,20
;int 21h


exit

main ENDP

END main
```

update:
i tried to change line 10
from
    FileName db "s151619.txt"
to
    FileName db "s151619.txt",0
and the error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
appeared on Line 11 now...

Comment: From the `assembly` tag info: *also specify the processor or instruction set your question is related to as well as what assembler you are using.*

Comment: You appear to be writing a mixture of 16-bit code (DOS interrupt 21h) and 32-bit MASM using Irvine library. So are you writing 16-bit DOS applications or 32-bit Windows applications?

Answer (score 3):

You're including `Irvine32.inc`, but do not use it. So remove it to get pure 16-bit code, because `Irvine32.inc` itself includes `SmallWin.inc` which contains the following setup directives:

```
.686P       ; Pentium Pro or later
.MODEL flat, stdcall
```

These set the mode to `Pentium Pro` instructions with a 32-bit `FLAT` model. For example, setting the 16-bit register `AX` to a 32-bit data segment value with

```
mov ax, @data`       ; 32-bit value to 16-bit register --- Don't work
```

would give you an error like this

> Error A2048: Operands must be the same size: 2 - 4

and several more on other instructions in 32-bit mode.

Your problem in line 11 occurs due to a name clash between 'handle' in `handle dw ?` and 'HANDLE' in `HANDLE TEXTEQU <DWORD>` from `SmallWin.inc`. So on assembling, your variable definition evaluates to

```
DWORD dw ?
```

which is invalid and gives you the error.

**Solution:**

- Remove `INCLUDE Irvine32.inc`
- Replace it with `.MODEL SMALL, STDCALL` - setting 16-bit mode
- Replace `exit` with the DOS exit call `mov ax,4C00h     int 21h`